# React - changing an uncontrolled input

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-state

I have a simple react component with the form which I believe to have one controlled input:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="add-support-staff-form">
                <input name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onFieldChange('name').bind(this)}/>
            </form>
        )
    }

    onFieldChange(fieldName) {
        return function (event) {
            this.setState({[fieldName]: event.target.value});
        }
    }
}

export default MyForm;
```

When I run my application I get the following warning:

> Warning: MyForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be
>   controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to
>   controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

I believe my input is controlled since it has a value.  I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

I am using React **15.1.0**

Answer (score 694, accepted):

> I believe my input is controlled since it has a value.

For an input to be controlled, its value must correspond to that of a state variable.

That condition is not initially met in your example because `this.state.name` is not initially set. Therefore, the input is initially uncontrolled. Once the `onChange` handler is triggered for the first time, `this.state.name` gets set. At that point, the above condition is satisfied and the input is considered to be controlled. This transition from uncontrolled to controlled produces the error seen above.

By initializing `this.state.name` in the constructor:

e.g.

```
this.state = { name: '' };
```

the input will be controlled from the start, fixing the issue. See [React Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) for more examples.

Unrelated to this error, you should only have one default export. Your code above has two.

Comment: It is difficult to read answer and follow the idea many times but this answer is the perfect way of story telling and making viewer understand at same time. Answer level god!

Comment: What if you have dynamic fields in a loop? e.g. you set the field name to be `name={'question_groups.${questionItem.id}'}`?

Comment: How would dynamic fields work. Am generating the form dynamically and then set the field names in an object inside state, do i still have to first manually set the field names in state first and then transfer them to my object?

Comment: This answer is slightly incorrect. An input is controlled *if the `value` prop has a non-null/undefined value.* The prop doesn't need to correspond to a state variable (it could just be a constant and the component would still be considered controlled). Adam's answer is more correct and should be accepted.

Comment: "We can [make] the React state be the 'single source of truth'. Then the React component that renders a form also controls what happens in that form on subsequent user input. An input form element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a 'controlled component'".

This is from the React docs linked in the answer. There is no mention of `null` or `undefined` values in that section as it is orthogonal to helping people unfamiliar with how a React controlled component works.

Comment: Yeah - this is technically the wrong answer (but helpful). A note on this - if you are dealing with radio buttons (whose 'value' is controlled a bit differently), this react warning can actually throw even if your component is controlled (currently).  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6779, and can be fixed by adding a !! to the truthiness of isChecked

Comment: example for a dynamicly created field is to initialize your input instead as `<input value={props.value} />` to `<input value={props.value || ""}/>` assuming you're passing the state value as a prop.

Comment: @fvgs thanks for the approach to solve my problem which i had faced recently.

Answer (score 192):

When you first render your component, `this.state.name` isn't set, so it evaluates to `undefined` or `null`, and you end up passing `value={undefined}` or  `value={null}`to your `input`.

When ReactDOM checks to see if a field is controlled, [it checks to see if `value != null`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/751b76e3518883c31b6105736c2b13839863fdef/src/renderers/dom/stack/client/wrappers/ReactDOMInput.js#L28) (note that it's `!=`, not `!==`), and since `undefined == null` in JavaScript, it decides that it's uncontrolled.

So, when `onFieldChange()` is called, `this.state.name` is set to a string value, your input goes from being uncontrolled to being controlled.

If you do `this.state = {name: ''}` in your constructor, because `'' != null`, your input will have a value the whole time, and that message will go away.

Comment: For what it's worth, the same thing can happen with `this.props.<whatever>`, which was the problem on my end. Thanks, Adam!

Comment: Yep! This could also happen if you pass a calculated variable that you define in `render()`, or an expression in the tag itself—anything that evaluates to `undefined`. Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks for this answer: even though it's not the accepted one it explains the issue far better than just "specify a `name`".

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how the controlled input works. It's worth noting that what matters here is not that a value of `undefined` is being passed initially. Rather, it's the fact that `this.state.name` does not exist as a state variable that makes the input uncontrolled. For example, having `this.state = { name: undefined };` would result in the input being controlled. It should be understood that what matters is where the value comes from, not what the value is.

Comment: @fvgs having `this.state = { name: undefined }` would still result in an uncontrolled input. `<input value={this.state.name} />` desugars to `React.createElement('input', {value: this.state.name})`. Because accessing a nonexistent property of an object returns `undefined`, this evaluates to the exact same function call—`React.createElement('input', {value: undefined})`—whether `name` is not set or explicitly set to `undefined`, so React behaves in the same way. [You can see this behaviour in this JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/adambrenecki/7y3nmxcd/1/)

Comment: On another note, ReactDOM actually checks if a field's value is `!= null` to determine if it's uncontrolled; I've updated my answer to add more detail about this. (Fun fact: React prefers that you make inputs uncontrolled by passing `undefined` or omitting the prop entirely—which, as already noted, have the same effect when you access it—so if you do explicitly pass `null` you get _two_ warnings!)

Comment: @AdamBrenecki Ah that's interesting! Thanks for checking on that. I was basing my comment on React's definition of a [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). I wanted to emphasize that a controlled component is defined as having its value tied to a state variable. The way they've implemented checking for a transition between a controlled and uncontrolled component is interesting because, as you noted, it uses a very coarse check without actually checking the source of the value.

Comment: This makes it very easy to change a controlled component to an uncontrolled component (and vice-versa) without it calling you out on it. Or the opposite if you assign `undefined` or `null` to the state variable. That said, it is an effective check for catching the most common anti-patterns such as in the original question.

Comment: @Don that is one important information, saving me a lot of time!

Comment: The thing that I'm not understanding is, What is the problem with changing from controlled to uncontrolled and vice versa. Why it is an error??

Comment: This behavior in React stinks to high heaven. Is there a way to change it before I rip out React?

Answer (score 91):

Another approach it could be setting the default value inside your input, like this:

```
 <input name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name || ''} onChange={this.onFieldChange('name').bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: <input name="name" type="text" defaultValue="" onChange={this.onFieldChange('name').bind(this)}/>

I think this would also work

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly was I was looking for. Are there any disadvantages or potential problems using this pattern I should keep in mind?

Comment: This worked for me, as fields are dynamically rendered from the API so I don't know the name of the field when the component is mounted. This worked a treat!

Comment: @JpCrow Good answer. You can read more about this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/476445/3850405 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator

Comment: value={post.body || ""}       THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 30):

I know others have answered this already. But a very important factor here that may help other people experiencing similar issue:

You must have an `onChange` handler added in your input field (e.g. textField, checkbox, radio, etc). Always handle activity through the `onChange` handler.

Example:

```
<input ... onChange={ this.myChangeHandler} ... />
```

When you are working with **checkbox** you may need to handle its `checked` state with `!!`.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={!!this.state.someValue} onChange={.....} >
```

> Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6779#issuecomment-326314716

Comment: this works for me, thanks, yeah, I am 100% percent agree with that, initial state is {}, so checked value will be undefined and make it uncontrolled,

Comment: Double bang solution works just fine, thanks!

Comment: This helped me. Thank you.

Comment: what if we are fetching data from an API and displaying it in a TextField?

Answer (score 21):

Simple solution to resolve this problem is to set an empty value by default :

```
<input name='myInput' value={this.state.myInput || ''} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: With pleasure :)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem.
the problem was when i kept the state info blank

```
  const [name, setName] = useState()
```

I fixed it by adding empty string like this

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
```

Comment: Thank you sir! this was my problem and fix

Answer (score 10):

One potential downside with setting the field value to "" (empty string) in the constructor is if the field is an optional field and is left unedited. Unless you do some massaging before posting your form, the field will be persisted to your data storage as an empty string instead of NULL.

This alternative will avoid empty strings:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: null
    }
}

... 

<input name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name || ''}/>
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was missing something really trivial.

`<input value={state.myObject.inputValue} />`

My state was the following when I was getting the warning:

```
state = {
   myObject: undefined
}
```

By alternating my state to **reference the input of my value**, my issue was solved:

```
state = {
   myObject: {
      inputValue: ''
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the real problem I was having

Answer (score 8):

When you use **`onChange={this.onFieldChange('name').bind(this)}`** in your input you must declare your state empty string as a value of property field.

**incorrect way:**

```
this.state ={
       fields: {},
       errors: {},
       disabled : false
    }
```

**correct way:**

```
this.state ={
       fields: {
         name:'',
         email: '',
         message: ''
       },
       errors: {},
       disabled : false
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If the props on your component was passed as a state, put a default value for your input tags

```
<input type="text" placeholder={object.property} value={object.property ? object.property : ""}>
```

Answer (score 6):

Set a value to 'name' property in initial state.

```html
this.state={ name:''};
```

Answer (score 5):

An update for this. For React Hooks use `const [name, setName] = useState(" ")`

Comment: Thanks 4 the update Jordan, this error is a bit hard to solve

Comment: Why `" "` and not `""`? This causes you to lose any hint text, and if you click and type you get a sneaky space before any data you enter.

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a fallback to '' if the this.state.name is null.

```
<input name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name || ''} onChange={this.onFieldChange('name').bind(this)}/>
```

This also works with the useState variables.

Comment: This was the best option for me as I purposefully have `undefined` as the value in my state. Can someone who downvoted please explain why? A bit down the page there is the same response as this one but with 55+ upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

> I believe my input is controlled since it has a value.

Now you can do this two ways the best way is to have a **state key** to each **input** with **1** *onChange* handler. If you have checkboxes you will need to write a separate *onChange* handler.

### With a Class component you would want to write it like this

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         myFormFields: {
           name: '',
           dob: '',
           phone: ''
         }
        }

      this.onFormFieldChange = this.onFormFieldChange.bind(this)
    }


// Always have your functions before your render to keep state batches in sync.
    onFormFieldChange(e) {
       // No need to return this function can be void
       this.setState({
         myFormFields: {
            ...this.state.myFormFields,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
         }
       })
    }


    render() {
       // Beauty of classes we can destruct our state making it easier to place
       const { myFormFields } = this.state
      
        return (
            <form className="add-support-staff-form">
                <input name="name" type="text" value={myFormFields.name} onChange={this.onFormFieldChange}/>
                <input name="dob" type="date" value={myFormFields.dob} onChange={this.onFormFieldChange}/>
                <input name="phone" type="number" value={myFormFields.phone} onChange={this.onFormFieldChange}/>
            </form>
        )
    }

}

export default MyForm;
```

Hope that helps for a class but the most performative and what the newest thing the devs are pushing everyone to use is *Functional Components*.  This is what you would want to steer to as class components don't intertwine well with the latest libraries as they all use custom *hooks* now.

### To write as a Functional Component

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyForm = (props) => {
    // Create form initial state
    const [myFormFields, setFormFields] = useState({
       name: '',
       dob: '',
       phone: ''
    })


   // Always have your functions before your return to keep state batches in sync.
    const onFormFieldChange = (e) => {
       // No need to return this function can be void
       setFormFields({
         ...myFormFields,
         [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
       })
    }

      
       return (
            <form className="add-support-staff-form">
                <input name="name" type="text" value={myFormFields.name} onChange={onFormFieldChange}/>
                <input name="dob" type="date" value={myFormFields.dob} onChange={onFormFieldChange}/>
                <input name="phone" type="number" value={myFormFields.phone} onChange={onFormFieldChange}/>
            </form>
        )

}

export default MyForm;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent buddy

Answer (score 4):

In short, if you are using class component you have to initialize the input using state, like this:

```
this.state = { the_name_attribute_of_the_input: "initial_value_or_empty_value" };
```

and you have to do this for all of your inputs you'd like to change their values in code.

In the case of using functional components, you will be using hooks to manage the input value, and you have to put initial value for each input you'd like to manipulate later like this:

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState({name: 'initialValue'});
```

If you'd like to have no initial value, you can put an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

In my case component was rerendering and throwing `A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled` error. It turned out that this behaviour was a result of not keeping `true` or `false` for checkbox checked state (sometimes I got `undefined`). Here what my faulty component looked like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WrappedFieldProps } from 'redux-form/lib/Field';

type Option = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

type CheckboxGroupProps = {
  name: string;
  options: Option[];
} & WrappedFieldProps;


const CheckboxGroup: React.FC<CheckboxGroupProps> = (props) => {

  const {
    name,
    input,
    options,
  } = props;

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState<{ [name: string]: boolean }>(
    () => options.reduce((accu, option) => {
      accu[option.value] = false;
      return accu;
    }, {}),
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    input.onChange(value);

    if (value) {
      setChecked({
        [value]: true, // that setChecked argument is wrong, causes error
      });
    } else {
      setChecked(() => options.reduce((accu, option) => {
        accu[option.value] = false;
        return accu;
      }, {}));
    }

  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      {options.map(({ value, label }, index) => {
        return (
          <LabeledContainer
            key={`${value}${index}`}
          >
            <Checkbox
              name={`${name}[${index}]`}
              checked={checked[value]}
              value={value}
              onChange={(event) => {
                if (event.target.checked) {
                  setValue(value);
                } else {
                  setValue(undefined);
                }
                return true;
              }}
            />
            {label}
          </LabeledContainer>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

To fix that problem I changed `useEffect` to this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  input.onChange(value);

  setChecked(() => options.reduce((accu, option) => {
      accu[option.value] = option.value === value;
      return accu;
    }, {}));

}, [value]);
```

That made all checkboxes keep their state as `true` or `false` without falling into `undefined` which switches control from React to developer and vice versa.

Comment: You want to make sure you have a cleanup function to ensure the state update stops a re-render from occurring on false positives triggering this effect to fire again if state updates above this component in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 3):

For people using `Formik`, you need to add a default value for the specific field `name` to the form's `initialValues`.

Comment: You'd better provide an example. It's hard to understand.

Comment: @DavidPiao it makes perfect sense to me, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using **react material ui** and **react-hook-form** Mostly you will get such issues when you misuse the react hook form with react material component (use attribute that should be used for uncontrolled element for controlled element, reset things incorrectly, do not set `value` attribute correctly ...etc) ex:

- Autocomplete:

  - you may get such issue when you do not set a default `null` value for the `value` attribute in case no value is given,
  - or when you mess up the use of `onChange` and `value` together.

  One possible way to fix such issue set `value ={value||null}` or code below. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295924/a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-autocomplete-to-be-controlled) for more details

  ```js
  onChange = {(event, values) => {
    onChange(values || null)
  }}
  ```
- Checkbox:

  - using `defaultChecked` for the controlled checkbox while this attribute is clearly mentioned in the doc that it should be used only when the component is not controlled,
  - another possible way that may lead to such an issue is using `checked={value}` without `defaultValue` this may lead to en error such, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715901/reactjs-error-warning/75792263#75792263) for more details

  ```
  React warning MUI: A component is changing the default checked state of    an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized
  ```

Comment: value ={value||null} also causes warning, maybe value ={value||""} is better

Answer (score 2):

This generally happens only when you are not controlling the value of the filed when the application started and after some event or some function fired or the state changed, you are now trying to control the value in input field.

This transition of not having control over the input and then having control over it is what causes the issue to happen in the first place.

The best way to avoid this is by declaring some value for the input in the constructor of the component. 
So that the input element has value from the start of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

```
import React from "react";

class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: "" };
        this.onFieldChange = this.onFieldChange.bind(this);
    }

    onFieldChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="add-support-staff-form">
                <input name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onFieldChange} />
        </form>
        );
    }
}

export default MyForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was spell mistake while setting the state which was causing defined value to be undefined.

This is my default state with value

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState(true);
```

my mistake was-

```
setEmail(res?.data?.notificationSetting.is_email_notificatio);
```

and the solution is -

```
setEmail(res?.data?.notificationSetting.is_email_notification);
```

last char was missing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with **type='radio'**

`<input type='radio' checked={item.radio} ... />`

the reason was that item.radio is not always **true** or **false**, but rather true or **undefined**, for example. Make sure it’s always **boolean**, and the problem will go away.

`<input type='radio' checked={!!item.radio} ... />`

[source](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6779#issuecomment-222162404)

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically setting state properties for form inputs and keeping them controlled you could do something like this:

```
const inputs = [
    { name: 'email', type: 'email', placeholder: "Enter your email"},
    { name: 'password', type: 'password', placeholder: "Enter your password"},
    { name: 'passwordConfirm', type: 'password', placeholder: "Confirm your password"},
]

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {} // Notice no explicit state is set in the constructor
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
     <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
       { inputs.length ?
         inputs.map(input => {
           const { name, placeholder, type } = input;
           const value = this.state[name] || ''; // Does it exist? If so use it, if not use an empty string

           return <input key={name}  type={type} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
       }) :
         null
       }
       <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault }>Submit</button>
     </form>    
  }
}
```