# React setState fails in catch of rejected Promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an error when setting the state within catch of a Promise. In the example below the Promise's `catch` is within the `onClickSave()` method. I believe I get the error, because I misunderstand the `this` context I am in. Here I want to use `this` to address the contents of the class `DialogUsersNewProps`. Coming from Java, where `this` behaves a bit different, I already got confused in JavaScript in the past. What must I do to set the state from within the `catch` of the rejected Promise?

Error from browser console:

```
/home/myuser/Documents/myprog/administration2/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
    in input (created by InputBase)
    in div (created by InputBase)
    in InputBase (created by Context.Consumer)
    in WithFormControlContext(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(WithFormControlContext(InputBase)))
    in WithStyles(WithFormControlContext(InputBase)) (created by Input)
    in Input (created by WithStyles(Input))
    in WithStyles(Input) (created by TextField)
    in div (created by FormControl)
    in FormControl (created by WithStyles(FormControl))
    in WithStyles(FormControl) (created by TextField)
    in TextField (created by DialogUsersNew)
    in div (created by DialogContent)
    in DialogContent (created by WithStyles(DialogContent))
    in WithStyles(DialogContent) (created by DialogUsersNew)
    in div (created by Paper)
    in Paper (created by WithStyles(Paper))
    in WithStyles(Paper) (created by DialogUsersNew)
    in DialogUsersNew (created by DisplayUsers)
    in DisplayUsers (created by DisplayChoice)
    in DisplayChoice (created by DisplayMain)
    in main (created by DisplayMain)
    in div (created by DisplayMain)
    in div (created by DisplayMain)
    in DisplayMain (created by App)
    in App
    in AppContainer
```

Failing TypeScript class:

```
import {
    Button,
    DialogActions,
    DialogContent,
    Paper,
    TextField,
    Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import { User } from '../../../data/model/user';
import { AddNewUserResponse } from '../../../data/services/add-new-user-response';
import { DialogMessage } from '../../dialogs/dialog-message';

export interface DialogUsersNewProps {
    onClickSave(user: User): Promise<AddNewUserResponse>;
    onClickAbort(): void;
}

export interface DialogUsersNewState {
    savingErrorMessage: string;
}

export class DialogUsersNew extends React.Component<DialogUsersNewProps, DialogUsersNewState> {
    private textFieldUsername: string;
    private textFieldPassword: string;

    public constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            savingErrorMessage: '',
        };
    }

    public render() {
        return <Paper>
            {this.state.savingErrorMessage !== '' &&
                <DialogMessage title='Saving error' content={this.state.savingErrorMessage} />
            }
            <DialogContent>
                <Typography variant='h5'>New user</Typography>
                <TextField  label='Username'
                            value={this.textFieldUsername}
                            className='w-100 fieldMargin'
                            onChange={(e: any) => this.onChangeTextFieldUsername(e.target.value)}
                            margin='normal'/>
                <TextField  label='Password'
                            type='password'
                            value={this.textFieldPassword}
                            className='w-100 fieldMargin'
                            onChange={(e: any) => this.onChangeTextFieldPassword(e.target.value)}
                            margin='normal'/>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.props.onClickAbort()} color='primary'>Abort</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.onClickSave()} color='primary' variant='contained'>Save</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </DialogContent>
        </Paper>;
    }

    private getUser(): User {
        // Generate new user based on props and textfields.
        return {
            password: this.textFieldPassword,
            username: this.textFieldUsername,
        };
    }

    private onChangeTextFieldUsername(content: string) {
        // Save textbox change.
        this.textFieldUsername = content;
    }

    private onChangeTextFieldPassword(content: string) {
        // Save textbox change.
        this.textFieldPassword = content;
    }

    private onClickSave() {
        // Send click save event to parent.
        this.props.onClickSave(this.getUser()).then((response: AddNewUserResponse) => {
            // Check if success has failed.
            if (!response.success) {
                // Save message in state.
                if (response.message) {
                    this.setState({savingErrorMessage: response.message});
                } else {
                    this.setState({savingErrorMessage: 'Undefined error.'});
                }
            }
        }).catch((response: AddNewUserResponse) => {
            // Save message in state.
            if (response.message) {
                this.setState({savingErrorMessage: response.message});
            } else {
                this.setState({savingErrorMessage: 'Undefined error.'});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `this` equal to in the catch of `onClickSave`?

Comment: Are you able to declare `onClickSave` as an arrow function. `private onClickSave = () => { ...`

Comment: @Nicholas I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. The `this` in the `catch` refers to the methods within the class `DialogUsersNew`. I am trying to set the state within `DialogUsersNewState` by accessing the `setState` method.

Comment: I was wrong about using `this` in private functions. It's only for `static` functions.

Comment: Try using the arrow function as mentioned earlier. It binds `this` to the parent scope.

Comment: Can you post the `render()` function, or at least wherever `this.onClickSave` is used?

Comment: @y2bd Added the render() method in the above post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, two issues happening here.

First, when using `<input />` components (or components that use them under the  hood like your `TextField`), if you want to control their value (`value={this.foobar}`) you have to **always** control the value. Where you are running into an issue is that `this.textFieldUsername/Password` is initially `undefined`, which will lead to the error as described here: [React - changing an uncontrolled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input)

Secondly, the reason that this is not occuring until you click on the save button is because

1. `this.textFieldUsername/Password` is not in React state, which means that when it changes it does not cause your Component to re-render, delaying the occurrence of the error.
2. `this.setState` *does* cause your component to re-render, giving those `TextField`s the values of `this.textFieldUsername/Password` and therefore causing the above error.
3. `.catch` blocks will catch errors in the pairing `.then` block. Since `this.setState` in your `.then` leads to the above error happening within `render()`, that error is bubbled up back to your Promise and lands you unhelpfully in the `.catch` block. I cannot find an SO post about this, so here is an MVP proving it is the case: https://codesandbox.io/s/2wzvj6p7v0.

Easiest fix would be

```
private textFieldUsername: string = "";
private textFieldPassword: string = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Error

You are calling `this.props.onClickSave` and it is not working.

## Reason

When you pass in the prop e.g. `<DialogUsersNew onClickSave={/*here*/}` ensure that you preserve the this context e.g. by [using an arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) `<DialogUsersNew onClickSave={()=>this.something()}`

Comment: I think I did what you suggest. I updated the above post by adding the `render()` method.

Comment: @Socrates What error are you running into after making this change? The console warning you posted in the OP doesn’t appear to be related to `onClickSave`, but instead the `TextField`s and their `value` prop.

Comment: @y2bd The error happens when invoking `this.setState({savingErrorMessage: response.message});`. The method `onClickSave()` is invoked by one of the two buttons in the `render()` method.