# React error: from controlled to uncontrolled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, controlled-component

EDIT: this question was marked as a duplicate by some users. Not sure if they read it before doing so. If someone did, please clarify in which sense this is a duplicate.

I have a component for checkboxes:

```
class Checkbox extends Component {
    onChange = (e) => {
        if (this.props.input) {
            this.props.input.onChange(e.target.checked);
        } else if (this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(e.target.checked, this.props.id);
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { input, value, className, label } = this.props;
        let inputValue = (input && input.value) || value;

        return (
            <div className={'Checkbox' + (className ? ' Checkbox--' + className : '')}>
                <input
                    className="Checkbox-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    checked={inputValue}
                />
                <span className="Checkbox-helper" />
                <span className="Checkbox-label" htmlFor="">
                    {label}
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This component returns an error when the value changes.

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type
>   checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from
>   uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a
>   controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
>   component.

But if I replace:

```
let inputValue = (input && input.value) || value;
```

with

```
let inputValue = value;
if (input) {
    inputValue = input.value;
}
```

Like so:

```
class Checkbox extends Component {
    onChange = (e) => {
        if (this.props.input) {
            this.props.input.onChange(e.target.checked);
        } else if (this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(e.target.checked, this.props.id);
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { input, value, className, label } = this.props;

        let inputValue = value;
        if (input) {
            inputValue = input.value;
        }

        return (
            <div className={'Checkbox' + (className ? ' Checkbox--' + className : '')}>
                <input
                    className="Checkbox-input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    checked={inputValue}
                />
                <span className="Checkbox-helper" />
                <span className="Checkbox-label" htmlFor="">
                    {label}
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It doesn't return any error. Why?

Comment: Duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input), controlled (using state)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - changing an uncontrolled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input)

Comment: Not sure if anyone did read my example before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: @tarzenchugh any explanation about why is a duplicate?

Comment: @rayhatfield want details

Comment: What is the `input` prop here?

Comment: If there is a question, why was it marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Of course, thank you very much.

`This.props.input` is a Final form —https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form—  `<Field>` component. My question is why different syntax causes different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility—there's not enough information here to say for sure—is that `input.value` is present but `false` (or falsy), so you fall back to the `value` prop, which is `undefined`, and you end up setting `checked` to `undefined` on your input.

This results in an uncontrolled checkbox.

Then, on a subsequent pass, either `input.value` or `props.value` has changed and you set `checked` to a real value, which means it's now a controlled input and react emits the warning.

In your initial case you'll get the `value` prop even if `input.value` is explicitly `false` or `0` or an empty string:

```
// if input.value === false here you get
// the fallback value which may be undefined
let inputValue = (input && input.value) || value;
```

In your modified case…

```
let inputValue = value;
if (input) {
  inputValue = input.value;
}
```

…you've avoided that scenario because you're predicating it on the presence of `input` itself rather than `input.value`.

Comment: Hm, now I understand… `a && b` doesn't evaluate `b` when the `a` is true, but when both `a` and `b` are true. And that's why if I use `let inputValue = input ? input.value : value:` there is no error.