# Toggle booleans and update obj with useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Currently, I have many checkboxes which all obviously correlate to boolean values that need to be passed on onSubmit. I had something like this initially:

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    charlie: false,
    // twenty or so more
  });

  ...

  <CheckboxComp
    aria-label="id"
    checked={value.alpha}
    onChange={() => setValue({ alpha: !value.alpha})}
    label="id"
  />
```

Which was throwing me:

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

Then I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61243124/16009119).

```
- Through Input

        const [state, setState] = useState({ fName: "", lName: "" });
        const handleChange = e => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                [name]: value
            }));
        };

        <input
            value={state.fName}
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            name="fName"
        />
        <input
            value={state.lName}
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            name="lName"
        />
   ***************************

 - Through onSubmit or button click
    
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            fName: 'your updated value here'
         }));
```

Which is nearly as close as I got but I was having trouble toggling true/false with something that was meant for strings on input. Any help, I know it's a silly question but it's a lot better than continuing onwards with useState(false) x20, the furthest thing from optimized.

Now I have something like this!

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    charlie: false,
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setValue(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          [name]: value
      }));
  };

  console.log(value)
  
  ...

  <CheckboxComp
    aria-label="id"
    checked={value.alpha}
    onChange={handleChange}
    name="alpha"
    label="id"
  />
```

but console.log shows

```
alpha: "true"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - changing an uncontrolled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input). Also your onChange call `() => setValue({ alpha: !value.alpha})` overwrites all other properties but `alpha`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, your `setValue` call is overwriting all properties but the explicitly named one. The example you showed passing a callback to `setValue` is not 'just for strings` it's simply a means of assigning a new value to a single property while maintaining all other properties. see: [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Here is a quick working snippet.

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    charlie: false,
    // twenty or so more
  });

  const checkChange = (e) => {
    const { id, checked } = e.target;
    setValue(prevValue => ({ ...prevValue, [id]: checked }))
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {Object.keys(value).map(k =>
          <div key={k}>
            <input type="checkbox" id={k} name={k} checked={value[k]} onChange={checkChange} />
            <label for={k}>{k}</label>
          </div>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: lets say instead of mapping out each checkbox I was to manually write each one, what changes would I need to make?

Comment: Replace all the `k`s with the property name of the state value. eg. `<input type="checkbox" id="alpha" name="alpha" checked={value.alpha} onChange={checkChange} />`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this block of code of Checkbox component:

```
    onChange={() => setValue({ alpha: !value.alpha})}
```

When you are updating the state by passing `{ alpha: !value.alpha }`, it is effectively removing all other keys from the object as you are modifying the object instead of ***modifying the particular value of a key while keep all others same***.

You should use spread operator or `Object.assign` to provide the new object after modification.

For your current code, when `setValue` is fired, your state object is left with `{ alpha: false }`, when it should be `{ alpha: false, beta: false, ...}`