# React Uncontrolled vs Controlled input. Why does it matter?

Tags: reactjs

When dealing with `form`s or `input`s in React, everyone's probably come across the following warning:

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.
> This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Why is it important for components not to change from Uncontrolled to Controlled, or vice versa? I understand that they are just warnings and that they are there for a reason, so you should fix it.

But *what is the reason* to fix it? *Why* should that not happen?

Comment: You might get information from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input

Comment: The answers explain different ways of _how_ to solve it, but no insight into _why_ it matters that it's solved

Comment: I am surprised that this question did not receive any attention over the past year.